# Visual Studio adds a circular reference when I drag and drop a user control from the Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have a user control C that is defined inside project P.  C is present as a ".NET Framework Component" in my Visual Studio Toolbox.  I open a form F (also defined inside project P) and drop C onto F.

Once I do that drop, Visual Studio **adds a reference under P pointing to P's own DLL**. This is unnecessary and causes tons of build errors like `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties...` after which it lists the exact same method twice.  If I go into References and delete the added reference, it builds correctly.

Can I prevent VS from adding this unnecessary reference?

*Summary (By SLaks)*:
In VS2010, adding a UserControl to a form in the same project automatically adds a reference to the project itself, causing problems.

Comment: This is a new bug in VS2010. I was going to ask this question myself this evening.

Comment: Does anyone know of any Knowledge Base article or other official information about this defect?

Comment: We have been seeing this lately, too. Since there aren't a lot of "me too"s so far, I think it will be up to us to find the pattern. Here's what I'm working with. VS2010 solution converted from VS2008. All projects are C#, originally targetting .NET v3.5, then modified to target .net v4.0. The UI project is WinForms. The UI project contains classes which wrap Infragistics controls. The wrapped controls are used on the forms instead of the raw Infragistics controls.

Comment: I'm seeing this also.  @Mel's description is accurate for my problem as well except I am not using Infragistics controls.  I'm only using ordinary WinForms controls.

Comment: I have the same problem, has anyone every found a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this has been around at least since visual studio 2008. I tried finding a possible fix back then, but could not find one. Sorry, but I think you cannot prevent the unnecessary reference and have to remove it every time it does that.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar symptoms but I think the cause was different than what you describe.  For me I kept implementing a class with a name that clashed with an existing class.  This led to ambiguous call and other compiler hell breaking loose.

A simple rename cleared it up.